# What's the difference between UML-Modeling and UML-design

Tags: uml

What's the difference between UML-Modeling and UML-Design? Or is it the same concept?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same thing.  Both refer to planning out your app (and documenting it) using UML.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, even when both are part of the Structural Model (aim to model the static structure of the scenario), they use different objects.

The Domain Model instances are real-world objects. It is concerned with the problem domain and attempts to create a useful working model of the domain in which you are creating a solution for.

On the other hand, Design Model instances are software objects, which may be technology frameworks, databases, user interfaces, etc. you are using to get working software. You can say that Design Model is inspired by the Domain Model.